# How to copy all the fine with a specific format like .txt and .png from a folder to another one in Linux Terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

Hi all I have a folder full of different format like the one that I am interested in are .png and .txt and I want to copy them in another folder from the terminal in Linux. Someone know how to that?

Comment: Use `man man` to learn about manual pages and `man cp` to learn about copying.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple Use cp command in Linux

=> Example:

```
cp *.txt /destination/folder/location/
```